# Predicting with a model created using multinom hangs and errors

Tags: r, nnet

I'm trying to use the `nnet` library to create a multinomial logistic regression model from my training data to see if I can use it to predict my test data.

I set everything up in R using this script:

```
library(nnet)

folder <- "C:/***/"
trainingfile <- "training-set.txt"
testfile <- "test-set.txt"

train <- read.table(paste(folder, trainingfile, sep=''), sep=",", header=FALSE)
train.classes <- t(train[1:1])
train.data <- train[2:16]

test <- read.table(paste(folder, testfile, sep=''), sep=",", header=FALSE)
test.classes <- t(test[1:1])
test.data <- test[2:16]

train.model <- multinom(V1 ~ ., train, maxit=450) #converges after roughly 430 iterations
```

This all works well and the function `multinom` reports convergence.

To use the model to predict to classify the test data I use:

```
predictions <- predict(train.model, test.data)
```

However I'm then greeted with the error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'V17' not found`. However when I inspect `train.model` I see that there is indeed an object 'V17'

```
> train.model
Call:
multinom(formula = V1 ~ ., data = train, maxit = 450)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)        V2 
B -12.9514837 1.0668464 
C -48.1154774 1.6160071 
D  -2.2901219 1.0062945 
E -39.4371326 0.6848848 
F -20.6759707 0.8613838 
G -21.4471217 1.2858480 
H -17.4302527 0.8102932 
I  -4.7391825 1.3124087 
J -12.3513130 1.1404751 
K -13.9557738 0.7574471 
L  -0.4915034 0.7191369 
M -14.0855382 0.8888810 
N  -0.4372225 0.6041747 
O -18.2596753 1.2708861 
P  -9.8504326 1.2672870 
Q -20.9940977 1.8104502 
R  -5.8030089 0.8677690 
S -12.9944084 0.8097735 
T -32.5636344 1.8977861 
U  -9.1752184 1.6059663 
V -13.5695897 1.4547335 
W  -6.2590220 1.1292715 
X  -4.5939135 0.7603754 
Y -15.6763068 1.6498374 
Z -37.1840564 0.7382329 

*SNIP*

         V17
  1.63319426
  1.93093207
  0.80392847
  1.79189803
  1.32248565
  1.72440154
  1.22022835
  1.03014847
  0.20977345
  2.40335443
  1.17253978
  0.65072776
  0.46675729
  1.16579165
  1.50787334
  1.41267773
  1.71666099
  0.72543894
  0.64857852
  0.32401569
  1.33290027
  0.83846524
  1.02863203
 -0.05005955
  0.13792242

Residual Deviance: 26196.1 
AIC: 27046.1
```

This is very strange, I now have no clue why the error is occurring. Anyway to get more data I tried calling `summary(train.model)` but that just totally hangs R forever. I've tried both the 32b and 64b versions of R 2.15.2 (the latest stable version) and the result is the same. Does anybody have a clue how I can resolve the errors/hangs and how I can rightly predict using the model created by `multinom`?

Comment: You are creating `train.model` using the dataset `train`. Did you perhaps want to use `train.data`? The columns of `train.data` are a subset of `train`, as those in `test.data` are a subset of those in `test`. As your code stands, if the column names of `train` are not present in `test.data`, then you will get an error like the one you describe.

Comment: I don't think that is right. I create a model mapping the first column (the class) to the other columns (data points) for each row in train. Train.data only contains the data points and not the classes.

Comment: You should not be checking for the presence of `V17` in `train.model` but rather in the column names of `test.data`.

Comment: @BenBarnes that's the winner, silly me I removed the last column by accident, it should be [2:17] must be because I'm so used to arrays starting at 0. I can now properly use the predict function however summary(train.model) still hangs R. If you could make your comment into an answer I will accept it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing from comments above:

Ensure that the following is true:

```
all(names(train)[-1] %in% names(test.data)) # [-1] to ignore V1
```

Otherwise, `predict` will throw an error.

And to add a little bit of value: In my experience, the reason for `summary.multinom` taking such a long time is that `vcov.multinom` is being called and the Hessian is being calculated. If you're making multiple calls to `summary(train.model)`, it would make sense to calculate the Hessian in the call to `multinom` (which may still take a while):

```
train.model <- multinom(V1 ~ ., train, maxit=450, Hess = TRUE)
```